# ¿Cómo puedo arreglar el error de Comunication Error (1001)?

Tags: java, java-ee

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el cual tengo que realizar una página en la que  tengo que conectarme con varias api, entre ellas, la de Wikipedia la cual uso para buscar información sobre un autor.

El caso es que mientras que cuando ejecuto la pagina en localHost, todo me funciona perfectamente, pero cuando ejecuto la página en Google Cloud, al realizar la busqueda de un autor obtengo el siguiente error: "Communication Error (1001) - The connector failed to complete the communication with the server".

Creo que el error se puede deber a que los protocolos que utiliza la página en local son HTTP, pero cuando los ejecuto en Google Cloud los protocolos que usan son HTTPS.

Este es mi código:

```
package aiss.model.resource;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.restlet.resource.ClientResource;
import org.restlet.resource.ResourceException;

import aiss.model.wikipedia.Query;
import aiss.model.wikipedia.Result;

public class WikipediaResource {
    private static final Logger log =
            Logger.getLogger(WikipediaResource.class.getName());

    private final String baseURL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=search&utf8=1&srsearch=";

    public Query getSearch(String query) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String autor = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
        String uri = baseURL + autor;

        log.log(Level.FINE, "URI:" + uri);
        ClientResource cr = null;
        Result search = null;
        try {
            cr = new ClientResource(uri);
            search = cr.get(Result.class);
            log.warning("SUCCESS: " + cr.getResponse().getStatus());
            return search.getQuery();
        } catch (ResourceException e) {
            log.warning("Error en la búsqueda en Wikipedia: " + cr.getResponse().getStatus());
            log.warning(uri);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

No tengo ni idea como se puede resolver este problema, aunque pienso que a lo mejor se podría arreglar agregandole algun tipo de cabezera a la peticion o algo.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Edicion 1: Añado el log entero del error en Google Cloud

[image: Pantalla de error de Google Cloud]

Comment: publica todo el resultado del error
para ver donde fue que se origino el error
o que libreria lo ocasiono. Para tener una mejor perpestiva de tu error

Comment: De acuerdo a este [foro](http://restlet-discuss.1400322.n2.nabble.com/Communication-Error-1001-The-connector-failed-to-complete-the-communication-with-the-server-tp7578738p7578743.html) y esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17855238/1305745) es posible que necesites otras librerias adicionales como `jsslutils`. Estan estas en tu proyecto?